# Services filling up taskbar as applications

Tags: windows-xp, taskbar

Windows XP, with Windows Classic theme

I've had a sporadic problem, where the task bar seems to fill up with lots of tasks, which seem to be names of services. When I open Task Manager, the Applications tab is filled with these names.
I can still continue to use my PC to an extent, but it's not possible to remove all these icons from the taskbar, and other Windows UI features (e.g. Start bar) tend to be 'hollow' so I only see the outline; meaning I have to restart. See screenshot:

[image]

The trigger seems to be clicking on the "Show Desktop" quick link when I have several applications open (e.g. Outlook, Excel). Has anyone else come across this? It's happened to me on my home machine before, but seems to happen more frequently (2-3 times a week) at work...

Comment: that is cool, because that it what is really going on :-)
I have never seen nor heard of such a thing, but there always did exist a program or two that could "show Hidden Windows" and give visable windows to all tasks.
 I wonder if some 3rd party program that serves some other purpose, is doing this?
I would suspect first any program that has to find a program based on its window.  a Tool that works based on certian programs running, and things like that.

Answer (score -1):

The picture is not clear. Have a Screenshot of the desktop rather than capturing with a camera.
And check your startup for invalid/malicious entries.
Get yourself a good anti-virus and scan thoroughly..

Comment: Did you even read the question? He made it quite clear he couldn't take a screenshot, and the rest of the problem seems to be well outlined.

Comment: Oooops, Seems I missed that part. Oh well, as windows doesn't have any native features like this, it's got to be the job of some malicious process. 
So, my second advice remains the same..

Comment: Turns out I can get a screengrab (didn't have access to the Start Menu, but I realised I could create a new Bitmap from the desktop to launch Paint...) - http://i48.tinypic.com/wlrlau.png . I don't know if this helps at all! Weird huh?